# sqlite binding error in python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm having a problem with the binding in this sqlite3 statement in python. Any help would be apreciated.  Thanks

```
print page
print section
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM docList WHERE pageFileName = ? AND sectionTitle = ?',(page,section,))
```

Here is the output

```
(u'current_reports.html',)
(u'Intro',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Work\Dropbox\Public\www\propagateIndex.py", line 65, in <module>
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM docList WHERE pageFileName = ? AND sectionTitle = ?',(page,section,))
InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
>>>
```

I have read a lot of other posts about this but I am not sure what to do still. Tried different

Answer (score 1):

`page` and `section` are tuples; you want to insert just the first elements. It's easiest just to concatenate these:

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM docList WHERE pageFileName = ? AND sectionTitle = ?',
            page + section)
```

or use indexing:

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM docList WHERE pageFileName = ? AND sectionTitle = ?',
            (page[0], section[0]))
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I always struggle with that!!